# ReactNative inside DialogFragment. Showing ReactNative powered ModalDialogs when app is in a BackgroundService mode

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty new to `ReactNative` and `Android` development.

I have some native `Java` based logic which shows `DialogFragment` on certain events while app is working in a `Background service` mode.

My goal is to use `ReactNative` code inside `DialogFragment`, or call `ReactNative` powered view while app is in a `BackgroundService` mode.

What would be the best strategy for that case? I can integrate `ReactNative` code inside FragmentActivity, but I haven't found any solution for integrating `RN` code inside `DialogFragment`.

Also I could listen from `JavaScript` to certain events which are yielded by `Java` code, but I'm not sure how to show `ModalDialog` from RN, when app is not open and is in a `BackgroundService` mode. What would you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: This explains how to bind between java and react native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: It's not relevant to the question, I know how to communicate between Java code and RN code.